# Which exercise program is better for fat loss?

Tags: weight-loss

I have never done any exercise before, and would like to start one but I am confused between these two fitness programs:

1. P90x
2. Lee Labrada's online 12 week program

Which one will help me better achieve my fat loss goals, or are there any better complete fitness program like these?

I am 21 yrs old, male and I weigh 85 kg (187 lbs) , height 5.8

any response shall be highly appreciated. 
thank u.

Comment: The x in p90x stands for extreme so if you have "never done any exercise before" you may want to consider p90 without the x.   Other [programs](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6553/need-to-get-back-into-shape-is-there-a-slightly-lighter-p90x-type-thing) you may consider. Also, check out some previous q/a: [Losing fat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-to-lose-fat-while-lifting-weights-and-not-doing-any-cardio/18913#18913),  [Losing weight](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/looking-for-some-advice-on-weight-loss-routine/2578#2578)

Comment: Good on you for taking your fitness seriously!

Comment: Exercise alone will not help you reach your fat loss goals. It takes  activity and nutrition to burn those fats.

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT - It likely doesn't matter which program you use from a weight loss perspective.*

Diet is more effective than exercise at promoting weight loss (for example, see [this link from Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/weight-loss/expert-answers/weight-loss/faq-20058292)

From my personal experience, I used a combination of diet and regular moderate exercise to go from 110 kg to 90kg in less than a year. Maintained that weight for a few years and then got into boxing and decided to go with regular intense exercise alone and got back up to 100kg... but I am far more physically fit than I was at 90kg.

Again from my personal experience you don't necessarily need to change what you eat so long as you have a good balance of veggies, fruit, protein, etc. Portion control is the key.

Comment: @JohnP - now edited to address the basic question.

Answer (score 2):

**user15736** Really answered the basic principle behind your question fairly well. Diet is the key part to any change in physical fitness (gaining weight or losing weight).

But I took a quick look at both programs, and I have to say I would go with

> **Lee Labrada's online 12 week program**

Home training is ideal in terms of efficiency, but lack of equipment and proper space can mean less of a "workout" and prolong the time it would take to reach the same goal.

In Lee Labrada's online 12 week program The workouts are formulated by grouping certain muscles with a good amount of high rep (10-12) weight training to burn fat and tone down, with cardio in between days.

Using **external weights** as opposed to just **body-weight** is what can give you a bigger advantage when training (excluding cardio days). That is why I would personally choose Lee **Labrada's online 12 week program** versus P90x. Although I'd even go as far as saying you should add a good 20 minutes of cardio to certain weight training days if you really want to burn off fat quicker.